# Select unique columns with max value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm sorry for a bit fuzzy title. Don't know how to describe it better.

I have table like this

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id      INT          NOT NULL,
  version INT          NOT NULL,
  data    VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, version)
);
```

With data like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo
VALUES
  (1, 1, '1.1'),
  (2, 1, '2.1'),
  (3, 1, '3.1'),
  (1, 2, '1.2'),
  (2, 2, '2.2'),
  (4, 1, '4.1'),
  (1, 3, '1.3'),
  (4, 2, '4.2');
```

I need to get all rows (or *N* rows with highest `id` values. This actually would be more often) with latest available `version` and unique `id`. I have two queries now that seems to be working. But I'm not confident enough in SQL to decide which is better of if there is even better approach. Also  I don't think that I need any additional index for this but again, suggestions are welcome. DB is PostgreSQL (9.5), I expect thousandth of rows (but it would not be 10000 in the near future probably).

Query 1:

```
test_db=# SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, version, data FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC, version DESC;
 id | version | data 
----+---------+------
  4 |       2 | 4.2
  3 |       1 | 3.1
  2 |       2 | 2.2
  1 |       3 | 1.3
(4 rows)


test_db=# SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, version, data FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC, version DESC limit 2;
 id | version | data 
----+---------+------
  4 |       2 | 4.2
  3 |       1 | 3.1
(2 rows)
```

Query 2:

```
test_db=# SELECT t.id, t.version, t.data FROM foo t
test_db-#   JOIN (SELECT id, max(version) as version from foo GROUP BY id) q
test_db-#     ON t.id = q.id AND t.version = q.version;
 id | version | data 
----+---------+------
  3 |       1 | 3.1
  2 |       2 | 2.2
  1 |       3 | 1.3
  4 |       2 | 4.2
(4 rows)

test_db=# SELECT t.id, t.version, t.data FROM foo t
test_db-#   JOIN (SELECT id, max(version) as version from foo GROUP BY id) q
test_db-#     ON t.id = q.id AND t.version = q.version
test_db-#   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2;
 id | version | data 
----+---------+------
  4 |       2 | 4.2
  3 |       1 | 3.1
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Your `DISTINCT ON` query is probably the best option, but note that you need to have an `ORDER BY` clause in order for it to be meaningful.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are righ. Lost it during copy-pasting. Edited post to fix.